# WiFi Drops Out after Suspend

Tags: wireless, suspend, fujitsu-siemens

I have a Fujitsu Siemens V5535 loaded with ubuntu 14.10. Of course, it's a netbook, and I'm pretty happy with how it's survived, despite all I've put it through. So overall, I'm pretty happy with it, considering what it's made to do and that I've forced it to do much more than it should be able to.

But with ubuntu, if I suspend, the WiFi drops out. The only way to fix it is to reboot. This is the only big problem I have with it. It does lack RAM, it's only got 1GB. So it is very slow, but when you only use it for browsing, that's not much of a problem! :-) hahaha

Thanks for your help guys :-D

Comment: Try turning WiFi off, either with a function key or with the switch in the menu bar, before putting it to sleep.

Comment: Hi, I've migrated to Lubuntu now. :-) WiFi dropping is no longer a problem. Thanks for your help anyway :-D